# Example of df.apply with multiple columns and axis=0

Tags: python, pandas

If I'm not mistaken, it seems like with [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), using:

```
df.apply(function, axis=1)
```

is used to pass each **row** to a the `function`. And then doing something like:

```
df['col'].apply(..., axis=0)
```

is used to send a **value** to a function. However, I'm wondering if one would ever use `axis=0` when using more than one column. If so, how could that be used?

Comment: if only one column ,series, apply pass axis is no need ~

Comment: @BEN_YO sure, but I'm not understanding the usage of `axis=0` with multiple columns. Could you please explain that?

Comment: You can pass all columns to apply with `df.apply(func, axis=0)` or leave out the axis and it will still be 0 by default. If `df` has more than one column and `func` is a _reduction_ (e.g. sum, mean, stdev...) then it will return a series with a value for each column.

Comment: @RichieV what might be a use case of passing all columns though?

Comment: It is the second case of the [doctest](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Comment: @RichieV yea with a consistent aggregation/reduction (all numbers, for example) I get that, but what about when it's not a reduction, is that ever used?

Comment: You can't use it that way. The `apply` is either across a single row or a single column. (of course you can `apply` across the same function all columns one by one), but you can't apply, at least easily with multiple columns. If you need something that would use two entire columns, like a weighted average, you'd write a function that passes the DataFrame, or separate Series. and do `my_func(df)`

Comment: It all depends on your data structure and your function, if it does not reduce then it could still do some computation that takes the column as input (normalization is a good example)... but as I said, it all depends on your data structure, you just passed a good example on your first line by passing __all rows__ instead of columns, but it is all the same to numpy

Comment: @ALollz that's an interesting way to explain how it works, thank you. Would you want to post an answer elaborating a bit on what you mean with an example and I can accept that?

Comment: @RichieV I see, so would it be accurate for me to say "Set axis=1 if you ever need to reference more than one field. Otherwise, you can ignore it (since axis is by default=0)" ?

Comment: My comment was about passing all columns or all rows as vectors, but apply will act on the full df. For selecting some columns you need to follow Allolz advice or put a filter in your function that selects the columns by name, dtype, position, or any other logic, keep in mind it must reduce, match shape, or broadcast to the same shape, otherwise it will fail

Comment: @RichieV thanks. Could you please clarify what you mean by `vector`? Is this a c++ vector, or...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataFrame.apply` passes a **single** Series (at a time) so you can "only" use it for operations on a single row or a single column at a time. Here I'll simply print what is passed when we `apply` along each axis:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1], ['b', 2]], index=['r1', 'r2'], columns=['c1', 'c2'])

# Applying along axis=0 passes each Column Series separately
df.apply(lambda x: print(x, '\n'), axis=0)
#r1    a
#r2    b
#Name: c1, dtype: object 

#r1    1
#r2    2
#Name: c2, dtype: int64 


# Applying along axis=1 passes each row as a Series
df.apply(lambda x: print(x, '\n'), axis=1)
#c1    a
#c2    1
#Name: r1, dtype: object 

#c1    b
#c2    2
#Name: r2, dtype: object
```

Notice that in the `axis=1` case we're still passing a Series. Now the Series is indexed by what used to be the columns, and the `name` is the row label. Also be careful, the `dtype` was upcast to object for both since that was the only container capable of holding both the integers and strings.

---

I used quotes above for "only" because with enough imagination you can use `apply` to deal with mutliple columns.There are better ways to do this, but this just shows it *is possible*. Here I'll use an apply to multiply all the `'val'` columns by the corresponding `'weight'` column. We do this by creating a custom function that also passes the entire DataFrame and then exploit the naming convention of the columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0,1, (15,4)),
                  columns=['val1', 'val2', 'weight1', 'weight2'])

def my_weight(s, df):
    return s*df[s.name.replace('val', 'weight')]

df.filter(like='val').apply(lambda col: my_weight(col, df))
#       val1      val2
#0 -0.175574  0.301880
#1 -0.032201  0.025987
#2 -2.063913  0.226745
#3 -0.617288 -0.220579
#4  0.912825  0.078496
```

Instead it would be much simpler to multiply directly:

```
df['val1']*df['weight1']
#0   -0.175574
#1   -0.032201
#2   -2.063913
#3   -0.617288
#4    0.912825
#dtype: float64
```